# Cropping image in numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy

I want to crop RGB images such that the upper half part of the image is removed. After cropping I want to concatenate the image to a numpy array (here images). But I get the following error `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`. I tried multiple things but I don't seem to have luck with any of my attempts.

My code looks like

```
images = np.zeros((1, 32, 64, 3))
image = get_image()  # has shape 1, 64, 64, 3
# removing the first coordinate didn't change the error.
images = np.concatenate([images, image[:, 32:63, :, :]], axis=0)
```

EDIT: The following modifications in `image[:, 32:63, :, :]` did not resolve the problem

a) [:, 32:63, :, :] -> [32:63, :, :]

b) [:, 32:63, :, :] -> [:][32:63][:][:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
images = np.zeros((1, 32, 64, 3))
image = get_image()  # has shape 1, 64, 64, 3
# removing the first coordinate didn't change the error.
images = np.concatenate([images, image[:, 32:, :, :]], axis=0)
```

As 32:63 leaves out the last element. (32:64 would be possible too)

Comment: Thank you! I get the desired output.